# Add click event handler to only some children

Tags: jquery

I have a few rows in my table in the following format,

```
<tr class = "parent">
    <td class = "first"> asdf </td>
    <td class> qwerty </td>
    <td class> zxcv </td>
    <td class> 1234 </td>
</tr>
```

I want to perform action A when I click on "asdf" and action B when any one of the remaining children of the row is clicked. I wrote,

```
//Action A
$('.first').live('click', function() { console.log('first clicked'); });

//Action B
$('.parent').children().not('.first').live('click', function() { console.log('others clicked'); });
```

For some reason the code for Action B is not working. I need the "live" attachment for both actions since rows can be added/deleted.

What should I do?

Comment: `$('.parent').find('td:not(.first)')` should work.

Comment: `What should I do?` Read the documentation for `.live`... `$('.parent').children().not('.first').selector` === `".parent.children().not(.first)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td class="first"> asdf </td>
    <td class> qwerty </td>
    <td class> zxcv </td>
    <td class> 1234 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

$('tr.parent').find('td').live('click', function(){
    if ($(this).is('.first')) {
        console.log('Has .first.');
    } else {
        console.log('Does not have .first.');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GnX4L/

Maybe a better way:

```
$('tr.parent').find('td').live('click', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':first-child')) {
        console.log('Is first child.');
    } else {
        console.log('Not first child.');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GnX4L/1/

Comment: What is the .find() for? Why don't you use $(".parent td")

Comment: Because it's typically faster to first find the outer match, then limit the inner search to that outer match.

Comment: Do you have any stats for that? Seems to me that jQuery is smart enough to search the smartest way..

Comment: It does depend (for instance, a `#id .selector` would be optimized due to how jQuery works). And for lightweight selections, it may not be an appreciable difference, I do it more out of habit now. But any specific implementation would need to be tested, so no, I don't have any stats to prove or disprove this assertion, just Paul Irish's informed opinion. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".parent td").live('click',function() {

if($(this).attr("class") == "first"){
  console.log('first clicked');
}else{
  console.log('every thing else clicked');
}

});
```

I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".parent").delegate(".first", "click", function() {
    console.log("A");
}).delegate(":not(.first)", "click", function() {
    console.log("B");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GnX4L/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use hasClass and don't use find(), waste of processor power :-)

```
$(".parent td").live('click',function() {

    if($(this).hasClass("first"){
      console.log('first clicked');
    }else{
      console.log('every thing else clicked');
    }

});
```