# Javascript click function inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

im not so good with javascript but i have searched for 5 hours now and no luck.

Im trying to make buttons work, if i write the code one-by-one it works fine and everthing is OK.

I can understand the problem.
The click part only works when the CLICK is actualy made. 
Am i right?
but how to i corret so it would work like i need?

Can i send the $(name) value to click function
so when my lets say  button-1 is clicked then  scrollTop: $(button-1-block) or am i over thinking in this case.

```
    var divHeight = 700
    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("blocks");
    var i = 1;

    for(i=1;i<blocks.length+1; i++) {
        var name = "#button-"+i;
        var blx = "#block-"+i;
        $(name).click(function(){
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(blx).offset().top - ( $(window).height() - divHeight )/2 
              }, 2100,'easeInOutExpo');
         });

    }
```

Comment: can you share your sample html code?

Comment: Are you sure `blocks.length` is not 0?

Comment: Well, first of all, you don't need the loop. In jQuery, you use selectors like `$('[id^=block-]').click(...)` to get all of the elements which start with `id="block-#"` and end in something else. This you can attach that `$.click()` to each of the elements in the selected list of elements you found. It's very easy.

Comment: try something similar to this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547845/add-click-event-handler-to-only-some-children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var divHeight = 700
//var blocks = $(".blocks");

$('[id^="button"]').click(function(){
     var block = '#block-' + this.id.match(/\d+/g).join("");
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(block).offset().top - ( $(window).height() - divHeight )/2 
     }, 2100,'easeInOutExpo');
});
```